# os.system unable to call file with left parenthesis '(' in filename

Tags: python, windows, os.system

I'm trying to call an executable that has parentheses in the name (e.g. `'test(1).exe'`).

With Python 3.6.2, when I try the following:

```
os.system('test(1).exe')
```

I get:

`'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
program or batch file.`

But if I change the filename to `'test1).exe'` by removing `'('`, then the following works successfully:

```
os.system('test1).exe')
```

Any ideas why the left parenthesis is causing an issue with `os.system`?

Comment: try with this `test\ \(1\).exe' inside `os.system()`

Comment: You need to escape shell special characters / separators if you're going to use `os.system()`. Or, from the documentation of the same function: '_The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; **using that module is preferable to using this function**. See the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes._'

Comment: If you're using Windows (as it appears), then you need to "escape" certain characters. Here's what it says about it in a Windows command-line reference help file I have: "The ampersand (`&`), pipe `(|`), and parentheses (`(` and `)`) are special characters that **must be preceded** by the escape character (`^`) or quotation marks when you pass them as arguments." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Found some online documentation about it on the [SS64 command-line reference](https://ss64.com/) website in a section titled [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Answer (score 3):

Using `subprocess.call()` without `shell=True` avoids the need to quote arguments in a shell-safe manner:

```
subprocess.call(["test(1).exe"])
```

Comment: You can omit ".exe" to help with cross-platform code. If `shell=True` is required for some reason, then the executable name needs to be quoted with double quotes, and pass the command line as a string instead of a list, e.g. `subprocess.call('"test(1)"', shell=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: put a '^' character in front of '(' like this:

```
os.system('test^(1).exe')
```

Comment: @martineau: judging by the error message the OP is running on Windows, the `^` is an escape character in cmd.exe, much like \.

Comment: Without any explanation, this is just voodoo.

Comment: mendlo: I might have not down-voted your answer if you had put that information in your answer.

Comment: Might specify explicitly that this is a Windows-only answer -- someone with the same problem on Linux might be disappointed to find it not working.